# In bootstrap, How do I make an image a dropdown?

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

In bootstrap, How do I make an image a dropdown?

Hi, I have created a dropdown in bootstrap, I want to put an image such that it will be the item to click so as to see the dropdown.

Here is my code below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Getting Started with Bootstrap</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-limanAbba-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

  </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LimanAbba</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-limanAbba-navbar-collapse-1">  

      <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li><a href="#">Freelance</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>\
           <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="caret"></span><ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Liman</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Code90</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Coding</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just put the image link on the dropdown button. See below code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body>   
<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .dropdown with image link.</p>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKhkr.png?s=128&g=1">
       <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want a pure image as the dropdown toggle, you can use an anchor (`a`) instead of a `button` to have only the image displayed.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>  

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Pure Image Dropdown</h2>
    <p>Click the image to see the dropdown</p>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" id="imageDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="imageDropdown">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```