# Use image as dropdown in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use an image (thumbnail image in navbar) as a Bootstrap dropdown. I tried the solution in [How do I make an image a dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551620/in-bootstrap-how-do-i-make-an-image-a-dropdown), but it didn't work.

The image will be the user's thumbnail image when logged in and I want a drop down for user settings, logout, etc.

Comment: _This seems fairly simple_ if you will show us your version of code.

Answer (score 2):

I tried it once again and checked out meetup dot com. I got the dropdown while clicking the image without the background but i could not find a way to add the caret.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <img class="btn dropdown-toggle" src="images/thumbnail_image.png" alt="dropdown image" data-toggle="dropdown" class="img-responsive">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: P.S. Just saw the code in your reply. Looks good. Glad i could help. :)

Comment: This works but I still get a white border/background when I click the image. I am using the img-responsive and the img-circle for the image.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite simple. All you have to do is use an 'img' tag between the button tags.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <img src="images/example_image.png" alt="dropdown image" class="img-responsive">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dropdown menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you still have problems, please attach your code along with you question. Hope this helps.

Comment: This adds a button outline around my image. I just want my thumbnail image with a caret to the right as the drop down, no button. Like the way it is done on meetup dot com.

Answer (score 0):

I have it the way I want by doing the following but there is no hand pointer on mouse over, I have to add the pointer style and I get a white background behind my image when I click for the drop down. Now I need to correctly style the drop down toggle to fix this. Thanks for your reply.

```
                        <li class="side-padded margin_left">
                        <div class="dropdown top_margin15">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <?php
                                echo '<img id="profile-img" class="img-circle img-responsive" src="'.base_url().'i/mbr/img/'.$this->auth_user_id.'.jpeg">';
                                ?>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown menu 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```